# Google App Scripts: How do you copy a row to the next available row in a new tab depending on the value in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to transfer a row (range A:AE) from sheet NSI to the next available row in Sheet1 if cell AE= 1.

My code doesn't seem to work, please could somebody help me?

Thank you!!

```
function myFunction() {
  function copyRows() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("NSI"); 
  var lastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":AE" + i);
    var cell = srcSheet.getRange("AE" + i);
    var val = cell.getValue();
//sets the target sheet depending on the exam in column AE
    if (val == "1") {
      var tarSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    }
//insets the row in the correct target worksheet  
    var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow()+1;
      tarSheet.insertRows(tarRow);
    var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow) + ":AE" + (tarRow));
      srcRange.copyTo(tarRange);    
  }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function copyRows() {
  var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("NSI");
  const vs = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 31).getDisplayValues();
  var tarSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if (r[30] == "1") {
      tarSheet.appendRow(r);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, shouldn't `r[0]` be `r[30]` since it is column `AE`? Also, I was wondering since if columns go beyond `AE`, it will also be copied and OP noted only `A:AE` should be copied. Wouldn't it be safer to use `31` as the column instead of `getLastColumn()` on `getRange`?